# How does discord.py rewrite turn names of functions into commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

A sample function for a command in Discord.py rewrite is the following:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", help_command=None)
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

The way that you would call the function in discord is `$say something`. How does Discord.py know the name of the function `say` in order to make it a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions have the `__name__` attribute which returns a string corresponding to the name of the function

```py
>>> def foo():
...     print("Inside foo")
... 
>>> foo.__name__
'foo'
```

In a decorator:

```py
>>> def my_decorator(func):
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...         print(f"The function name is: {func.__name__}")
...         return func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> 
>>> @my_decorator
... def foo():
...      print("Inside foo")
... 
>>> foo()
'The function name is: foo'
'Inside foo'
```